# NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/ServiceRegistry

Tags: java, hibernate

I can't figure out why I am getting this error in my Servlet but not in my test class: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/ServiceRegistry`

I have hibernate 5.1.14

The servlet is below. Code crashes at `BookDAO dao = DAOUtilities.getBookDAO();`. I tested and it actually crashes on all of my DAOs. It just is getting a data access object (DAO) so that I can retrieve all books in the db. I'll also include the working test class for comparison. Let me know if you need to see anything else.

EDIT: I'm not using Maven (at least not knowingly). I'm adding JARs manually.

```
package examples.pubhub.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import examples.pubhub.dao.*;
import examples.pubhub.model.*;
import examples.pubhub.utilities.DAOUtilities;

/*
 * This servlet will take you to the homepage for the Book Publishing module (level 100)
 */
@WebServlet("/BookPublishing")
public class BookPublishingServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        //Get our DAOs
        System.out.println("Getting DAOs");
        BookDAO dao = DAOUtilities.getBookDAO(); //fails here
        TagDAO tgdao = DAOUtilities.getTagDAO();


        // Grab the list of Books from the Database
        List<Book> bookList = dao.getAllBooks();

        //Grab the tags for each book from the Database
        HashMap<String, String> booktags = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for(Book b : bookList) {
            String tags = "";
            List<Tag> tempTags = tgdao.getTagsByBook(b);
            for(Integer i=0; i<tempTags.size(); i++) {
                tags+=tempTags.get(i).getName()+";";
            }
            tags = tags.substring(0, tags.length() - 1);
            booktags.put(b.getIsbn13(), tags);
        }


        // Populate the list into a variable that will be stored in the session
        request.getSession().setAttribute("books", bookList);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("booktags", booktags);

        request.getRequestDispatcher("bookPublishingHome.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

The full log up to the point of crashing:

```
16:02:47,813 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.7.0.Final
16:02:48,101 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.3.2.Final
16:02:48,110 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.3.1.Final
16:02:48,215 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 12.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 4.0.0.Final) starting
16:02:49,460 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
16:02:49,480 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.2.2.Final
16:02:49,482 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
16:02:49,563 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found PubHub.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called PubHub.war.dodeploy
16:02:49,590 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
16:02:49,616 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-8) XNIO version 3.6.2.Final
16:02:49,622 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-8) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.6.2.Final
16:02:49,649 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
16:02:49,667 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 43) WFLYRS0016: RESTEasy version 3.5.0.Final
16:02:49,671 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
16:02:49,675 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
16:02:49,677 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
16:02:49,744 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
16:02:49,745 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYTX0013: The node-identifier attribute on the /subsystem=transactions is set to the default value. This is a danger for environments running multiple servers. Please make sure the attribute value is unique.
16:02:49,746 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.4.7.Final)
16:02:49,762 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 2.0.0.Final starting
16:02:49,811 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.5.Final
16:02:49,818 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
16:02:49,825 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
16:02:49,828 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=5.0.2.Final
16:02:49,835 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 36) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.4)
16:02:49,838 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
16:02:49,944 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 64 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
16:02:49,944 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
16:02:49,993 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
16:02:50,066 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'C:\wildfly/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
16:02:50,075 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
16:02:50,094 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
16:02:50,859 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
16:02:51,069 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYPAT0050: WildFly Full cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
16:02:51,081 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYDM0111: Keystore C:\wildfly\standalone\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
16:02:51,090 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\wildfly\standalone\deployments
16:02:51,113 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "PostgreSQL_JDBC_JAR" (runtime-name: "postgresql-42.2.2.jar")
16:02:51,114 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "PubHub.war" (runtime-name: "PubHub.war")
16:02:51,127 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
16:02:51,168 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
16:02:51,468 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.2.0.Final (Apache CXF 3.2.2) 
16:02:51,506 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
16:02:51,732 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 42.2)
16:02:51,747 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = postgresql-42.2.2.jar
16:02:51,752 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/PostgresDS]
16:02:51,891 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 42.1)
16:02:51,920 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = PubHub.war_org.postgresql.Driver_42_1
16:02:52,038 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-3) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Bastille' 9.1.6.Final
16:02:52,176 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
16:02:52,331 WARN  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) UT015020: Path /admin/* is secured for some HTTP methods, however it is not secured for [TRACE, HEAD, DELETE, CONNECT, OPTIONS, PUT]
16:02:52,345 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/PubHub' for server 'default-server'
16:02:52,355 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "PostgreSQL_JDBC_JAR" (runtime-name : "postgresql-42.2.2.jar")
16:02:52,385 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "PubHub.war" (runtime-name : "PubHub.war")
16:02:52,441 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
16:02:52,443 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
16:02:52,443 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
16:02:52,443 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 12.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 4.0.0.Final) started in 5573ms - Started 776 of 969 services (318 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
16:07:01,538 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Getting DAOs

16:07:01,542 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /PubHub/BookPublishing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/ServiceRegistry
    at examples.pubhub.servlets.BookPublishingServlet.doGet(BookPublishingServlet.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$769/1655281877.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1526)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$770/1853163366.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1526)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$770/1853163366.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1526)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$770/1853163366.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1526)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$770/1853163366.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry from [Module "deployment.PubHub.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:199)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    ... 51 more
```

Here is test class:

```
package examples.pubhub.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import examples.pubhub.dao.*;
import examples.pubhub.model.*;
import examples.pubhub.utilities.DAOUtilities;

public class TestTagDAO {
    //isbn:1111111111111
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String isbn = "1111111111111";
        String name1 = "test1";
        String name2 = "test2";
        String name3 = "test3";
        String name4 = "test4";
        List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

        TagDAO tagDao = DAOUtilities.getTagDAO();
        BookDAO bookDao = DAOUtilities.getBookDAO();

        Book book = bookDao.getBookByISBN(isbn);
        books = bookDao.getAllBooks();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you added hibernate-core dependency to your pom.xml ?

if not add it something like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.x.x</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I'm not using maven. I added the hibernate jars to my build path in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue a lot recently using Eclipse actually. I find that sometimes, randomly (and annoyingly), Eclipse doesn't generate the .class files required. Normally I delete the /bin/ directory from my project and then refresh and clean my project and it will generate the respective .class files. Before you do this, check to see if the .class files are there in the /bin/ directory.

In addition to this, if you are adding the .JAR files manually, check to see if they are in the build path.